# Different filters for different url patterns

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that provides mainly REST endpoints, authentication is done via token (sent in `Authorization` header) where I have my own `TokenAuthenticationFilter` added before `LogoutFilter` to set the security context.

In the process of creating an admin console, I want admin authentication to be separate from regular users, as I'm not sharing tables between `Admins` and `Users` for several reasons, on the database level I have the following `user,user_token,admin,admin_token`. So in order to accomplish this, I thought of several solutions:

1. Let the current `TokenAuthenticationFilter` handle user/admin token
   auth. This however will require to either: Modify the filter to
   determine whether it's an admin or a user token based on url pattern
   (so for example if it's `/admin/**`, the filter will know which
   service to call) **or** have the admins header unique from the users
   (i.e. User sends U-Auth header, Admin sends A-Auth header) and the filter will act based on header name. This all
   doesn't sound good to me.
2. Specify a set of filters to apply per url pattern, for example
   `/admin/**` will have `AdminTokenAuthFilter` added to the chain,
   while any other pattern will have the old
   `TokenAuthenticationFilter` in the chain. This sounds better than
   the earlier approach but I'm having trouble to implement it. I tried
   to register my own `FilterRegistrationBean` inside my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Example:

```
 @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean adminFilter(){
     FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
     filterRegBean.setFilter(new AdminTokenAuthFilter());
     List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
     urlPatterns.add("/admin/*");
     filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
     return filterRegBean;
 }
```

This seems to work but I'm unsure if it's proper practice also I'm concerned about one thing, I found that this adds the filter to the springs `originalChain` of filters, not to the `additionalFilters` that seems to apply when adding filters regularly in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` using  `http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, LogoutFilter.class)`. I don't want to alter springs original filter chain, i'd rather have my custom filters in the additional filter chain. Can anyone elaborate on this please?

3. Create two separate dispatcher servlets and make each one listen to
   a specific url pattern and I suppose each `dispatcherServlet` will have its own security configuration.

Can anybody share some knowledge on what's the best approach in such a scenario?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ended up writing two security configurations, the first one applies to a specific antmatcher, the second one is for any other url pattern. Like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "x.x.x")
public class NewSecurityConfiguration {
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class BackendSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired CustomSystemUserDetailsService customSystemUserDetailsService;
        @Autowired SystemTokenAuthFilter systemTokenAuthFilter;
        @Autowired CustomLogoutFilter customLogoutFilter;
        @Autowired UnauthorizedEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Bean(name="systemAuthenticationManager")
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {                
            auth.userDetailsService(customSystemUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
            http.antMatcher("/system/**")
                    .addFilterBefore(systemTokenAuthFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(customLogoutFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/system/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .logout().disable();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FrontEndSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .addFilterBefore(userTokenAuthFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(customLogoutFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/access/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/ref/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/ticket_parser/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/reset_password/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/link_profile/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/email_verification/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/ref").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/flightstats/alert").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/airline/list").access("authenticated or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1')")
                    .antMatchers("/airport/list").access("authenticated or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1')")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().authorizeRequests()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .formLogin().disable()
                    .logout().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but all your custom filters are applied to `/*` not only to your `antMatcher` specified

Comment: @ClaudioPomo First filter `BackendSecurityConfiguration` is applied to `/system/**`, second filter `FrontEndSecurityConfiguration` is applied to anything other than `/system/**`. Correct me if you believe I'm wrong.

Comment: Cool, that saved my day